# WebRTC local camera preview resolution decreases for network speed

Tags: webrtc, webrtc-android

I want to scan text page while call is going. What I do is, take frames from local video preview and send it to server for processing.

Before call starts, preview quality and resolution is highest. But when call starts resolution of capturer is decreasing. I can see that `onFrameResolutionChanged` event is called on local renderer.  I'm guessing that Web RTC is changing resolution because of internet speed.

I don't want to change the local display resolution.
I have this issue on IOS and Android WebRTC library.
What can I do to prevent local camera preview resolution from decreasing?
I tried `videoSource.adaptOutputFormat` function, but it just sets maximum quality and by the time preview still decreases.

Update:
What was I searching was `enableCpuOveruseDetection = false`. It have be set in

```
val config = PeerConnection.RTCConfiguration(servers);
config.enableCpuOveruseDetection = false
```

This works good for android, It does not resize local preview quality.
But in IOS there is no `enableCpuOveruseDetection` in RTCConfiguration() class. So in IOS problem still remains.